# Issue with size drop down on Magento

Tags: jquery, magento, prototype

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var optionFileUpload = {
    productForm : $('product_addtocart_form'),
    formAction : '',
    formElements : {},
    upload : function(element){
        this.formElements = this.productForm.select('input', 'select', 'textarea', 'button');
        this.removeRequire(element.readAttribute('id').sub('option_', ''));

        template = '<iframe id="upload_target" name="upload_target" style="width:0; height:0; border:0;"><\/iframe>';

        Element.insert($('option_'+element.readAttribute('id').sub('option_', '')+'_uploaded_file'), {after: template});

        this.formAction = this.productForm.action;

        var baseUrl = '<?php echo $this->getUrl('*/product/upload') ?>';
        var urlExt = 'option_id/'+element.readAttribute('id').sub('option_', '');

        this.productForm.action = parseSidUrl(baseUrl, urlExt);
        this.productForm.target = 'upload_target';
        this.productForm.submit();
        this.productForm.target = '';
        this.productForm.action = this.formAction;
    },
    removeRequire : function(skipElementId){
        for(var i=0; i<this.formElements.length; i++){
            if (this.formElements[i].readAttribute('id') != 'option_'+skipElementId+'_file' && this.formElements[i].type != 'button') {
                this.formElements[i].disabled='disabled';
            }
        }
    },
    addRequire : function(skipElementId){
        for(var i=0; i<this.formElements.length; i++){
            if (this.formElements[i].readAttribute('name') != 'options_'+skipElementId+'_file' && this.formElements[i].type != 'button') {
                this.formElements[i].disabled='';
            }
        }
    },
    uploadCallback : function(data){
        this.addRequire(data.optionId);
        $('upload_target').remove();

        if (data.error) {

        } else {
            $('option_'+data.optionId+'_uploaded_file').value = data.fileName;
            $('option_'+data.optionId+'_file').value = '';
            $('option_'+data.optionId+'_file').hide();
            $('option_'+data.optionId+'').hide();
            template = '<div id="option_'+data.optionId+'_file_box"><a href="#"><img src="var/options/'+data.fileName+'" alt=""><\/a><a href="#" onclick="optionFileUpload.removeFile('+data.optionId+')" title="Remove file" \/>Remove file<\/a>';

            Element.insert($('option_'+data.optionId+'_uploaded_file'), {after: template});
        }
    },
    removeFile : function(optionId)
    {
        $('option_'+optionId+'_uploaded_file').value= '';
        $('option_'+optionId+'_file').show();
        $('option_'+optionId+'').show();

        $('option_'+optionId+'_file_box').remove();
    }
}
var optionTextCounter = {
    count : function(field,cntfield,maxlimit){
        if (field.value.length > maxlimit){
            field.value = field.value.substring(0, maxlimit);
        } else {
            cntfield.innerHTML = maxlimit - field.value.length;
        }
    }
}

Product.Options = Class.create();
Product.Options.prototype = {
    initialize : function(config) {
        this.config = config;
        this.reloadPrice();
        document.observe("dom:loaded", this.reloadPrice.bind(this));
    },
    reloadPrice : function() {
        var config = this.config;
        var skipIds = [];
        $$('body .product-custom-option').each(function(element){
            var optionId = 0;
            element.name.sub(/[0-9]+/, function(match){
                optionId = parseInt(match[0], 10);
            });
            if (config[optionId]) {
                var configOptions = config[optionId];
                var curConfig = {price: 0};
                if (element.type == 'checkbox' || element.type == 'radio') {
                    if (element.checked) {
                        if (typeof configOptions[element.getValue()] != 'undefined') {
                            curConfig = configOptions[element.getValue()];
                        }
                    }
                } else if(element.hasClassName('datetime-picker') && !skipIds.include(optionId)) {
                    dateSelected = true;
                    $$('.product-custom-option[id^="options_' + optionId + '"]').each(function(dt){
                        if (dt.getValue() == '') {
                            dateSelected = false;
                        }
                    });
                    if (dateSelected) {
                        curConfig = configOptions;
                        skipIds[optionId] = optionId;
                    }
                } else if(element.type == 'select-one' || element.type == 'select-multiple') {
                    if ('options' in element) {
                        $A(element.options).each(function(selectOption){
                            if ('selected' in selectOption && selectOption.selected) {
                                if (typeof(configOptions[selectOption.value]) != 'undefined') {
                                    curConfig = configOptions[selectOption.value];
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }
                } else {
                    if (element.getValue().strip() != '') {
                        curConfig = configOptions;
                    }
                }
                if(element.type == 'select-multiple' && ('options' in element)) {
                    $A(element.options).each(function(selectOption) {
                        if (('selected' in selectOption) && typeof(configOptions[selectOption.value]) != 'undefined') {
                            if (selectOption.selected) {
                                curConfig = configOptions[selectOption.value];
                            } else {
                                curConfig = {price: 0};
                            }
                            optionsPrice.addCustomPrices(optionId + '-' + selectOption.value, curConfig);
                            optionsPrice.reload();
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    optionsPrice.addCustomPrices(element.id || optionId, curConfig);
                    optionsPrice.reload();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
function validateOptionsCallback(elmId, result) {
    var container = $(elmId).up('ul.options-list');
    if (result == 'failed') {
        container.removeClassName('validation-passed');
        container.addClassName('validation-failed');
    } else {
        container.removeClassName('validation-failed');
        container.addClassName('validation-passed');
    }
}
var opConfig = new Product.Options(<?php echo $this->getJsonConfig() ?>);
//]]>
</script>
```

Before merge JS , above code was working.
But after merge, Here are the three main problems JS errors showing in firebug:

- ReferenceError: $ is not defined
- TypeError: Property 'handleEvent' is not callable.
- TypeError: opConfig is undefined

And due to this, size drop down box is not changing price with size change value in drop down.

How to resolve this?